# How to "easily" produce flawless Javascript code for mobile platforms?

Tags: javascript, mobile, compatibility

I'm currently trying to find the best route to "easily" develop websites that work great on the following plateforms : MAC/PC (IE6+, FF3+, Chrome, Safari, Opera), iOs/Android (all existing mobile browsers)

Most importantly, I want to avoid separating the mobile version from the rest.
I want to achieve a good looking website that uses the same HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript for all platforms.

Concerning the HTML5/CSS3 part, I'm very happy with the result.
The tough part comes from the Javascript.

At first sight, jQueryMobile seemed to be the best option for such a job.

But I noticed several drawbacks : 
- just adding the library makes fonts look kind of "blocky" on non-mobile platforms
- I'm not too fond of using their GUI
- the library lacks useful functions (ie: detection of elements leaving/entering the viewport)

As I said, I prefer to take care of the GUI myself with robust HTML5/CSS3 code.
For the viewport manipulation, I've found http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport but it doesn't work on my Android phone and I'm unable to test my own javascript code on all platforms anyway.

So, do you guys know tools that would help me outpout custom made javascript that would run flawlessly on every mobile plateform?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: IE6? **Please** don't make that mistake. You'll end up shooting yourself trying to make it understand HTML5/CSS3.

Comment: I always used plain jQuery and it works well on every platform I tried, including android devices.. then it depends on how much "mobileish" you want to make your interface transformation for small viewports..

Comment: Linus : No problem with that since I've been doing this for years. For the CSS part I use CSS3 Pie which works fine on IE6. The only issue for me is Javascript on mobiles. Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated :) Thanks for your input!

Comment: Exactly. You just said it. **For years.** It's time to let go. Everyone has dropped IE6 support. **[Even Microsoft has](http://www.ie6countdown.com/).**

Comment: you have to remove IE6 from your requirements list else you will never have a perfect product

Comment: redShadow : unfortunately, I'm not as lucky as you. jQuery doesn't do viewport manipulation out of the box for instance. I was tempted to mix jQuery code with some pure Javascript but I'm afraid it wouldn't work on platforms I can't test. That's the dilemma :)

Comment: Scott and Linus : even if I drop IE6 support, how would it help me with the current issue which is only about javascript on mobiles?

Comment: It would help you by enabling you to focus on actual development and not worrying during said development whether or not the cool stuff you just coded *actually* works on IE6 or if there's an obscure hack you'll need your end-product to include when *one* visitor is actually coming along with that dinosaur.

Comment: When you figure out how to *easily* produce *flawless* code on *any* platform, you will be a multi billionaire

Answer (score 2):

HTML5, CSS3 and IE6 are kind of mutual exclusive.

Try to write clean code and make sure it [validates](http://validator.w3.org/) otherwise IE will render it in quirks mode.
Avoid a lot of pure javascript. Use libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) where it's appropriate.
Then, try to make it work on IE6. You may find useful projects like [css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com/) but it's all just a wrapper.

An alternative solution is to use [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).

Comment: +1 for *mutual(ly) exclusive*. Another +1 if you drop "kind of".

Comment: @LinusKleen: It is "kind of" mutual exclusive, because folks try sometimes to do both. It's painful even to try but... Anyhow, It's not exactly "mutual exclusive" if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Michal : Thanks a lot for the info about GWT. I'll have a look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

**For HTML/CSS:**

Does [Mandible](https://github.com/socialgenius/Mandible) suit your needs?

**For Javascript:**

All major frameworks "work" cross-platform and cross-browser, and tend to mask  "irregularities" between environments. What's driving your choice here should be how much functionality or structure you want your framework to provide, balanced with the added processing requirements and load-time overhead that downloading and running bulky frameworks will incur when running on a slower mobile device.

Here's a few for reference:

[Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) gives a common baseline of useful functionality, and is very small.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is good for dom manipulation and selection. It's got some of the extra spice in underscore, but I don't think that's the focus. It's features make it bulky, but it also supports and has a wide range of plugins.

[Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) is like a minimalist jquery. It's footprint is much smaller, making it a good choice for mobile apps, but it doesn't match jQuery in functionality. It also doesn't have access to jQuery's world of plugins.

[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) requires Underscore and jQuery/Zepto, but gives you a robust way to build and manipulate models. It's very good for dealing with state machines, remote data and keeping templates and the DOM from getting out of control.

Hope that helps. When you make a decision on what platform to go with, let us know what you went with and why.

**Other notes**
- [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) seems to be the go-to mobile scrolling upgrade. Never used it myself, tho.
- jQueryMobile is specifically designed as a framework to help build HTML UI's for mobile devices. If you're building your own robust HTML5/CSS code, you probably don't need it's help.
- **Don't bother spending the time to support IE6 or 7**. Unless you're redoing the AARP website, your target audience does not use them.

Comment: AARP website! +1 I'm cracking up.

Comment: @Jordan : Thanks a lot for some of these libraries I've never heard of before! I'll have a look.

Comment: @Jordan : as for iScroll, I won't use it because I prefer to develop websites that don't require any zooming from the user. Instead, I use a combination of viewport meta with fluid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd lean heavily on jQuery .. [it even tries to work on IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616618/jquery-and-browser-compatibility) .. with some success I'd attest. No reason to not use the latest 1.7 version and take advantage of HTML5/CSS3 features where you can ..

Comment: Thanks a lot but how do I do when what I need to do can't be done via jQuery?